# iPod no wireless networks problem

Tags: network, wifi, ipod-touch, ipod, ios

My daughter has an **iPod Touch 4th generation** I think it is with **iOS 6**. We have a problem with it whereby **it doesn't show any wireless networks at all**. Previously, it connected fine and would show networks available without issue.

*Note: Like a lot of iPods it has been dropped in the past and ended up with a cracked screen which has been replaced.*

On the two most used networks, I've restarted the routers to no avail.

The only network it 'sees' is when I turn my iPhone 5 into a personal hotspot. It then sees and connects to that wireless network.

I've also tried manually entering the SSID details of the two home networks but it immediately returns something along the lines of '**Cannot connect to ...**'.

Additionally, when first going into **Settings>Wi-Fi** it briefly displays the circular 'I'm doing something' next to the '**Choose a Network**' text but then disappears.

I've obviously restarted the iPod and **Reset Network Settings**.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

lets try this one step at a time, first go in to your settings- **general**, then scroll down to **reset** and tap **reset all network settings** *this will remove all your previous passwords and internet connections*. then just for the hell of it, reboot!

this should fix your problem, if not, let me know and we can figure out the best possible fix for your problem!

Comment: Hi there, many thanks for your answer. I've done that and the same thing is happening (or not as the case may be).

Comment: well i think the next and easyest way is to backup your device and reset it, once reseted try to see if it works,if it doesnt work we can problebly say its hardware if it does work once restored, we can establish it being softtware, witch is a good thing and then restore the software and take it from there

Answer (score 1):

This happens sometimes with me on my iPhone 5. I read somewhere a long time ago, when I still had an second generation iPod touch, that the way to resolve this problem is to turn on and then turn off **Airplane Mode** under settings very quickly several times.

In short, switch that damn switch on and off for like 4 to 5 times, that should resolve your problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This didn't work though. Because I can get it to connect via my phone's personal hotspot, I'm going to connect it and then update to the latest OS.